# nodejs swagger router is redirecting on using multiple routes

Tags: express, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm currently using https://github.com/apigee-127/swagger-tools for swagger documentation on my server. I also have client with proxy route to server as in when I'm on client if I do http://{client_url}/server will take to {server_url}. The problem is:

The swagger documentation comes pretty much fine if I load http://{server_url}/docs but not when I do http://{client_url}/server/docs . It just redirects  to http://{client_url}/docs. Is there a way to set multiple base paths for swagger documentation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that [swagger-combined](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-combined) v1.2 can help you.

if you config "base_path" and "route_match" correctly, I will work perfectly for you.